# Non binary Enum flags

Tags: c#, enums, flags

In c# it is quite common to find the following Enum structure

```
[Flags]
public enum Permission
{
    Read = 1 << 1,
    Create = 1 << 2,
    Update = 1 << 3,
    Destroy = 1 << 4
}
```

which allows you to join enums like this: `Permission.Read|Permission.Create`

I am now faced with a different sort of requirement, and the solutions I have come up with are problematic IMO.

I need to allow some sort of enum implementation to multiple types of premissions - some contradicting, and some aren't

and I want the following sort of functionality

```
[Flags]
public enum Permission
{
    Read1 = 1,
    Read2 = 2,
    Read3 = 3,

    Write1 = 10,
    Write2 = 20,
    Write3 = 30,

    Update1 = 100,
    Update2 = 200,
    Update3 = 300,

    Destory =  1000,

    Other = 10000,

    SomethingElse = 100000,

}
```

when this won't work `Permission.Read1|Permission.Read2` mainly because it means a user now has a reading permission level 3

besides using different bit flag for each Permission (which will require my db to hold a much larger integer than a INT for a very bad reason), or having a different enum (and column) per permission (which will limit my flexibility with the permissions) , and having no form of compile time verification (I guess I can create some sort of a workarroundish runtime verification) do you have any other idea?

Comment: Is it a different type of permission or is it a different object that the permission is on? ie. Read1 is read on object type XXX, Read2 on YYY, and Read3 ... etc?

Comment: This structure is mainly for illustration. The actual permission reguards to a level of permission for different resources as in Read1..3 is for object xxx and Write1..3 is for object YYY

Comment: Then you should change the structure. If it were a type it would have 2 properties: `PermissionFlags`, `ObjectType` (same for a table in a relational database, 2 columns). ObjectType would be the thing that the permission applies to. Keep your permissions as generic as possible. I doubt that there is a solution that would enable you to catch illegal combinations of permissions at compile time, you would have to create run-time validation and/or add validation logic in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your db doesn't need to store bigger than int. 32bits can accommodate lot more values for unique bit flags. Following hex values are unique binary bit flags. `Read1 | Read2` won't equal `Read3`

```
[Flags]
public enum Permission
{
    Read1 = 0x00000001,
    Read2 = 0x00000002,
    Read3 = 0x00000004,

    Write1 = 0x00000008,
    Write2 = 0x00000010,
    Write3 = 0x00000020,

    Update1 = 0x00000040,
    Update2 = 0x00000080,
    Update3 = 0x00000100,

    Destory = 0x00000400,

    Other = 0x00000800,

    SomethingElse = 0x00001000,

}
```

You can probably organize these better by blocking certain bit blocks as Read, Write etc. E.g. you can block Read to be blocked for first 8 bits, write for next 8 bits so on and so forth. That way, you can accommodate future changes and also use bit masking effectively.

Comment: It does limit me to a certain amount of permission types though - and since this is a new system I can't be sure it will stay that way. Since I can safely assume there won't be more than 10 permissions per action - and each user has only one action required - using more than a 16 bit integer seems wasteful to me - even though I can settle for a 32 bit integer.